# Random string - Copy and insert through code

Tags: c#, string, copy, paste

iam trying to get something to work...
I want to pass a value/string to (i dont know the name in english...its the place where selected things get copied when you press CTRL + C) and then 
release it on an Web Page with CTRL-V.

I have a console application which generates
random strings i want to copy and paste onto a Web Page on Mozilla/Chrome etc.

Is this possible from the point iam ?
And if yes, can someone show me the direction ?

Comment: the word you want is 'clipboard'. This is possible. This guide should be what you want. http://automatetheplanet.com/implement-copy-paste-csharp-code/

Comment: The term you're looking for is called the [clipboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_(computing)). If you want to copy the strings to the clipboard, there's a [class for that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx). If you want to send the keys directly to an open browser window, you'll want to look into [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You are referring to the clipboard, if you are working on C# you can play around with  Clipboard.SetText("Hello"); and Clipboard.GetText();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way
Be sure to add a reference to [System.Windows.Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            string myRandomSting = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars,   20).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());

            Thread thread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetText(myRandomSting));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();
        }
    }
```